# Double firing of function referencing self in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple script which :

- displays a message after 3 seconds if user has not clicked by then (using a setTimeout),
- then if user clicks within 5 seconds, then the message should not appear within the defined setTimeout,
- after this previous click if the user does not click for 5 seconds, then the user will see the message and so on...
- this goes on a like a loop.

My script acually works but I have an issue because it seems it is double firing "exponentially". I think my error is how I created this "loop" and self referencing the setTimerForMsg inside itself.

Here is a Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3wm7z576/11/

Here is the code:

**html**

```
<div id="zone">
  <span id="msg" class="displayNone">this is the messager</span>
</div>
```

**js**

```
setTimerForMsg(3000, 5000);

function setTimerForMsg(initial_timelaps, new_timelaps) {
      var timer = setTimeout(showMsg, initial_timelaps);
      $("#zone").on('click', function(e) {
        //if user clicks before msg appears (but after timer was initiated )
        clearTimeout(timer);
        //if user went beyond timer laps and msg already visible on Step (n)
        //remove it when move to Step (n+1)
        $('#msg').addClass('displayNone');
        console.log("message1");
        //loop the process for the next Step
        setTimerForMsg(new_timelaps, new_timelaps);
      });
    }
    function showMsg() {
      $('#msg').removeClass('displayNone');
      console.log('message2');
    }
```

This issue is important because while this script is simple, in my real app it does other things that could drain the browser performance so I can't have them be done 64 times!

And you can see here in the console of the Demo, each time I click the events occur twice : 2 times , then 4 times then 8, then 16, then 32 times, and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$("#zone").off('click', ...` to remove the eventListner you previously added. Otherwise you're just adding more and more click actions.

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: your suggestion put me in the right direction. In the end I changed on(click) by one(click). It works.

Comment: I also thought of another option. You can set up a function, a single function, to *always* run on button click, but change an internal function that it runs every time. `var fun = function(){}; $('button').click(function(){ fun() });` Do this outside of setTimerForMsg, but inside of setTimerForMsg you can change the definition of `fun`. That would make it only run once per click.

Comment: @Mathieu set up example of that other possible solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rc51z7d8/)

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all your new_timelaps parameter is unused, this might cause some confusion.

As for the exponential growth in logs, this is caused by the fact that you don't remove your event listener, so everytime the time for your interval is passed or you click ur button another click event with the same function is aplied to your button.

How you would solve this is by using 
`$( "#zone").unbind( "click" )`
to make sure the event is only aplied once and not get aplied again or the old ones get removed.